# birt reports JavaScript conditional expression

Tags: javascript, birt, maximo

I'm trying to get a formula scripted properly,  can some one help me please. I'm using Birt 3.7.1. thanks. This is for a *Maximo* report

```
if(row["special"] == 'W' && row["metername"] == null){
false} *** I need this coded --don't hide --> must have a task ***

else{

true}



if(row["special"] == 'W' && row["metername"] != null){

false} *** I need this coded --don't hide --> must have task --> view ***

else if(row["special"] == 'W' true

else true}
```

Comment: You should edit the question it is not clear at all: what do you mean by "I need this coded --> must have a task"?

Comment: Hi Dominique, Im sure I do.  I was trying to see how to add several conditions within the same if statement before it goes to an else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but if you're looking to just get your code here formatted validly, here you go:

```
if (row["special"] == 'W' && row["metername"] == null) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}



if (row["special"] == 'W' && row["metername"] != null) {
    return false;
} else if (row["special"] == 'W') {
    return true;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure its the most practical code, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks Aweary, but I need the part of the script where I have asterisks coded.  Trying to see how to do a condition with a must.